# HSQLDB Configuration with Spring - BeanCreationException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I'm trying to configure a HSQLDB using Spring, but I receive following **ERROR:**

```
Error creating bean with name 'hsqlDataSource' defined in class path resource [/config/HSQLDBConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed;
```

**CODE:**

```
package at.irian.bibi.priceindexer.config;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class HSQLDBConfig {

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource) {
      ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
      resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/schema.sql"));

      DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
      dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
      dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
      return dataSourceInitializer;
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource hsqlDataSource() {
      BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      basicDataSource.setDriverClassName(org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.class.getName());
      basicDataSource.setUsername("sa");
      basicDataSource.setPassword("");
      basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:priceindexerdb");
      return basicDataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(Environment environment, DataSource dataSource) {
      String[] packageOfModelBeans = {Listing.class.getPackage().getName(), Residential.class.getPackage().getName(), LotsAndLand.class.getPackage().getName()};

      LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

      factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
      factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(buildHibernateProperties(environment));
      factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(packageOfModelBeans);
      return factoryBean;
  }

  protected Properties buildHibernateProperties(Environment environment) {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", environment.getProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", environment.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", environment.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));

    hibernateProperties.setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode", environment.getProperty("javax.persistence.validation.mode"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", environment.getProperty("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag", environment.getProperty("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag"));

    return hibernateProperties;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public HibernateTransactionManager   hibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
  }
}
```

If I kick out the HSQLDBConfig my program starts without trouble. I really don't know what causes the trouble.

I also tried to debug it and the Exception is thrown at `return basicDataSource`

Does anyone have an idea of what could cause the error?

**EDIT**

**STACKTRACE:**

```
2015-08-02T14:29:39.281 ERROR 11143 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsqlDataSource' defined in class path resource [at/irian/bibi/priceindexer/config/HSQLDBConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsqlDataSource' defined in class path resource [at/irian/bibi/priceindexer/config/HSQLDBConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:752) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:752)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) ~[spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952) [spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941) [spring-boot-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at at.irian.bibi.priceindexer.Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at at.irian.bibi.priceindexer.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsqlDataSource' defined in class path resource [at/irian/bibi/priceindexer/config/HSQLDBConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsqlDataSource' defined in class path resource [at/irian/bibi/priceindexer/config/HSQLDBConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
... 27 common frames omitted
... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsqlDataSource' defined in class path resource [at/irian/bibi/priceindexer/config/HSQLDBConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hsqlDataSource' defined in class path resource [at/irian/bibi/priceindexer/config/HSQLDBConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
... 29 more
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
... 29 common frames omitted
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.java:62)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1559)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:146)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runSchemaScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:77)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initialize(DataSourceInitializer.java:71)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.java:62) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1559) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:146) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runSchemaScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:77) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initialize(DataSourceInitializer.java:71) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.8.RELEASE.jar:1.1.8.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
... 51 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to solve the problem by deleting all hibernate, hsqldb,.. dependencies from `pom.xml` and importing them **carefully** again.